# Add Chart Inside a Textbox using VBA in word

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word, textbox, shapes

I want to add a chart inside a textbox using VBA in Microsoft word.
I have tried using

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart()
```

API;

with cursor inside the textbox and still it doesn't produce the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify where the chart is to be placed it will simply be added to the document. If you had looked at the [help text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addchart2), IntelliSense or the Object Browser you would have seen that the method takes a `Range` as an argument. To place the chart in a specific location the range is required.

For example:

```
Set shp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart(Range:=Selection.Range)
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but it gives a COMexception saying Requested Object is not available

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Are you running the code from Excel?

Comment: No, running from Word

Comment: That code works perfectly when run from Word so there must be something else in your code that is causing an issue.